# is it possible to have absolutely positioned elements affect position of sibling elements?

Tags: css

I've recently started making a website for my family's company but I've ran into a slight issue with positioning. I use this for positioning the footer (which I think is pretty typical):

```
.footer-container{
    background:#f7f7f7;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

The problem is, is that I have a sibling div class above the footer which is relatively positioned. Since absolutely positioned elements are removed from normal flow, the relatively positioned div overlaps behind the footer. This makes it so that parts of text/images will be hidden behind the footer as well. In addition, if I want to use absolutely positioned elements inside the sibling div class, I'll have to take into account the height of the footer since I can't just use something like `bottom:0;`. I don't really know how to do this since I didn't specify the footer height because I want it to be relatively the same height for different resolutions. Is there some way to fix this issue?

Comment: If you are trying to create a footer which 'sticks' to the bottom of the screen you should never use `position: absolute;`. Instead use a sticky footer https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/User58/1vjpw1h4/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of [Ryan Fait's HTML5](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/) sticky footer.  I believe this should work for you.

The HTML

```
<div class ="wrapper">
    <div id="sibling">Sibling</div>
    <div class="push"></div>
<div>
<div class="footer-container">Footer</div>
```

And the CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#sibling {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 700px;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; 
}

.footer-container, .push {
    height: 100px;
}

.footer-container {
    background:#f7f7f7;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/User58/1vjpw1h4/4/)